# Does the trial index of typical CHSH experiments constitute a "hidden variable"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality

In typical [experiments related to the CHSH inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality#A_typical_CHSH_experiment) there are individual detections being made by two separate (analyzer-and-)detector systems, "System $A$: $(D_A^+, D_A^-)$" and "System $B$: $(D_B^+, D_B^-)$", respectively. These individual detections are put in relation to each other through a coincidence monitor, to satisfy the requirement that at each (valid) trial "$j$"

- there is exactly one detection of either detector $D_A^+$ or of detector $D_A^-$ recorded, and
- there is exactly one detection of either detector $D_B^+$ or of detector $D_B^-$ recorded.

Correspondingly, for each (valid) trial $j$ there are obtained "counts" $n_j^{++}$, $n_j^{+-}$, $n_j^{-+}$, and $n_j^{--}$,
where

- $n_j^{++} = 1, \qquad n_j^{+-} = 0, \qquad n_j^{-+} = 0, \qquad n_j^{--} = 0$
  if detector $D_A^+$ and detector $D_B^+$ had contributed detections in trial $j$;
- $n_j^{++} = 0, \qquad n_j^{+-} = 1, \qquad n_j^{-+} = 0, \qquad n_j^{--} = 0$
  if detector $D_A^+$ and detector $D_B^-$ had contributed detections in trial $j$;

etc.

The experiment generally consists of four separate subexperiments, where counts are recorded from four **disjoint** sets of trials "$J_{\mu}$" ($\mu \in \{1,2,3,4\}$). Each of these separate subexperiments is also characterized by a specific value (or narrow value range) of "[(relative) angle $\theta_{\mu}$ between the two detector systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem#Overview)",
$$\theta_{\mu} :\approx \frac{1}{2}~\text{ArcCos}\big[~\frac{\sum_{j \in J_{\mu}}[~n_j^{++} + n_j^{--} - n_j^{+-} - n_j^{-+}~]}{\sum_{j \in J_{\mu}}[~n_j^{++} + n_j^{--} + n_j^{+-} + n_j^{-+}~]}~\big]$$ $$ = \frac{1}{2}~\text{ArcCos}\big[~\frac{\sum_{j \in J_{\mu}}[~n_j^{++} + n_j^{--} - n_j^{+-} - n_j^{-+}~]}{\sum_{j \in J_{\mu}}[~1~]}~\big],$$

$$ \frac{1}{2}~\text{ArcCos}\big[~\text{Min}\big[~1, \frac{\sum_{j \in J_{\mu}}[~n_j^{++} + n_j^{--} - n_j^{+-} - n_j^{-+}~] + 1}{\sum_{j \in J_{\mu}}[~1~]}~\big]~\big] \le \theta_{\mu} \le \frac{1}{2}~\text{ArcCos}\big[~\text{Max}\big[~-1, \frac{\sum_{j \in J_{\mu}}[~n_j^{++} + n_j^{--} - n_j^{+-} - n_j^{-+}~] - 1}{\sum_{j \in J_{\mu}}[~1~]}~\big]~\big].$$

(Typically, trials for these four separate subexperiments are collected such that the four corresponding values $\theta_{\mu}$ are, nearly, in no particular order: $\frac{\pi}{8}, \frac{\pi}{8}, \frac{\pi}{8}$ and $\frac{3~\pi}{8}$.)

**My questions:**

Does the trial index ("$j$") constitute a "hidden variable" (for the experiment under consideration)?

If so: Does the trial index constitute a "non-local hidden variable" (for the experiment under consideration)?,

And: Is it (nevertheless) possible to express the "count correlation $n_j^{++} + n_j^{--} - n_j^{+-} - n_j^{-+}$" of each trial as a product,

$$n_j^{++} + n_j^{--} - n_j^{+-} - n_j^{-+} \equiv a[~\theta_{\mu}, j~] \times b[~\theta_{\mu}, j~],$$

such that

$-1 \le \sum_{j \in J_{\mu}}[~a[~\theta_{\mu}, j~]~] \le 1, \qquad$ and $\qquad -1 \le \sum_{j \in J_{\mu}}[~b[~\theta_{\mu}, j~]~] \le 1$

?